# Why my flutter project fails building ios app?

Tags: flutter, xcode, dart, build, ios-simulator

When I run `flutter run` in my flutter project it fails building the ios app and I get this error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            2.1s
Failed to build iOS app
**Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.**
```

I already updated flutter, my software (currently on macOS Sonoma 14.0), I restarted a couple of times my Mac, I deleted and reinstalled xcode app, deleted and reinstalled ios Simulator, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Please Open keychain access and follow these steps.

1- Lock the 'login' keychain.
2- Unlock it, enter your PC account password.
3- Clean Project in the product menu.
4- Build it Again.

it works fine for me.